# Sorting HashMap

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of `HashMap`. Each `HashMap` contains many key-value-pairs. I want to sort the `ArrayList` by the value of the key `distance` in the `HashMap`.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayListHashMap = 
    new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

{
    HashMap hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hashMap.put("key", "A key");
    hashMap.put("value", "B value");
    hashMap.put("distance", 2536);

    arrayListHashMap.add(hashMap);
}

{
    HashMap hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMap.put("key", "B key");
    hashMap.put("value", "A value");
    hashMap.put("distance", 2539);
    arrayListHashMap.add(hashMap);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to sort with a custom comparator:

```
Collections.sort(arrayListHashMap, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> m1, HashMap<String, String> m2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(m1.get("distance")).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(m2.get("distance")));
    }
});
```

Note that I assumed all your values are strings which is not the case in your example (distance is an int value).

Comment: though this way is correct but it sometimes doesnt give right results when the values are in double

Answer (score 7):

Add all the `HashMap`s to a list and sort it using a custom `Comparator` like this:

```
Collections.sort(arrayListHashMap, new Comparator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(HashMap<String, Object> o1, HashMap<String, Object> o2) {

        return ((Integer) o1.get("distance")).compareTo(
                   (Integer) o2.get("distance"));
    }
});
```

---

Full example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    List<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayListHashMap = 
        new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    {
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hashMap.put("key", "A key");
        hashMap.put("value", "B value");
        hashMap.put("distance", 2536);

        arrayListHashMap.add(hashMap);
    }

    {
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hashMap.put("key", "B key");
        hashMap.put("value", "A value");
        hashMap.put("distance", 2539);
        arrayListHashMap.add(hashMap);
    }

    Collections.sort(arrayListHashMap, 
        new Comparator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(
                HashMap<String, Object> o1,
                HashMap<String, Object> o2) {

            return ((Integer) o1.get("distance")).compareTo(
                       (Integer) o2.get("distance"));
        }
    });


    System.out.println(arrayListHashMap);
}
```

Comment: Be careful when comparing ints via `i1-i2`. Just think about one of them being `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.